# Symfony2: How to import existing database into different bundles

Tags: import, symfony, entity, doctrine-orm, bundle

I've seen a lot of posts here which describes the separation of concerns regarding organizing your app in bundles which work on their containing entities. But none of them states the point that these entities are related through different bundles.

As I already have an existing database which contains tables for posts, comments, tags, users, roles and some more I want to import this definition into my new symfony2 project.
My problem is that I would like to have that in different bundles like BlogBundle, UserBundle, StaticBundle, ..., but I do not know how to import the respective entities into the right bundle.
Further problem is that the user entity is referenced inside the post and comment entity so how should I do that. When I import the post, comment, tag into the BlogBundle, the user entity does not exist yet.

Can anyone guide me with a hint on how to go on with that process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entities are shared between bundles (of course).
If you want to do a blog, you can create a UserBundle (which could override the awesome [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) for example), and a BlogBundle.
UserBundle will contain your User entity, BlogBundle will contain your Post and Comment entities.
Now an example of code:

In your UserBundle:

```
<?php

namespace YourVendorName\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_user_table")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourVendorName\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name")
     */
    private $name;

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

In your BlogBundle:

```
<?php

namespace YourVendorName\BlogBundle\Entity;

class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="body", type="text")
     */
    private $body;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="YourVendorName\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $author;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

So you reference an entity in another bundle thanks to such annotations:

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="YourVendorName\UserBundle\Entity\User")
```

Anyway, you should really read the [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html), it might help you understand everything.

Comment: thx for your answer. that's exactly what i was looking for, although I was already thinking about that way. Stuck only at the point of "auto generating" entities from existing database into different bundles. But now I realized that still some hands on are necessary :-) I will try it this way!

Comment: Yeah, if your question is "Is Doctrine smart enough to dispatch entities into different bundles with the command doctrine:mapping:import", the answer is no :) You just have to move your entities into the good folders. And don't forget that doctrine:mapping:import is just a helper and still requires you to complete the generated entities.

Comment: You are absolutly right, it's a helper tool. I will now finish my user and role entities in my userbundle and will continue with the references from my blogbundle afterwards.